# An example in $L^p$ space.

Tags: lp-spaces

I am trying to find two sequence $f_n$ and $g_n$ that converge in $L^2$ to $f$ and $g$
$$f_n \rightarrow f~~ in ~~L^2$$ and
 $$g_n \rightarrow g~~ in ~~L^2$$

that $f_ng_n \in L^2~~~and~~ fg\in L^2$. but 
$$f_ng_n$$ not converge to
$fg$ in $L^2$.  and I don't know when we say $f_n\rightarrow f$in $Lp$
means $||f_n-f||_{Lp}\rightarrow 0$ or $||f_n||_{Lp}\rightarrow ||f||_{Lp}$

Comment: To answer your last question, $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L_p$ means that $\|f_n-f\|_p\rightarrow 0$.  $\|f_n\|_p\rightarrow\|f\|_p$ does not guarantee that $f_n\rightarrow f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can look for a sequence $f_n = \lambda_n \mathbf{1}_{A_n}$, where $\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_n$ is measurable such that:

- $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$ (that is ${\lambda_n}^2 \,\mu(A_n) \to 0$)
- but $f_n^2 \not\to 0$ in $L^2$ (for instance ${\lambda_n}^4 \,\mu(A_n) \to 1$)